# Running Ros Openni Tracker from bag files

Tags: ros, openni, openi-tracker, bagfiles

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a bag file which has /camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw. I was thinking to receive data and create depth nodes from this topic in ros openni tracker rather than the live data from the sensor.
As far as i have investigated running on the recorded data in Openni works for only '.oni' files. ROS openni tracker works well with recorded oni file but how to make it run on the raw depth data from a bag file is the question.
One option could be to run the NiViewer and record the data in an .oni file in parallel but it does not seem to be a nice solution as it will make the frame rate to drop low.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33764/running-ros-openni-tracker-from-bag-files/) by [tayyab](https://answers.ros.org/users/2123/tayyab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to do it back then. You can find the respective piece of code [here](http://tayyabnaseer.blogspot.de/2012/04/running-ros-openni-tracker-with.html).

---

Originally posted by [tayyab](https://answers.ros.org/users/2123/tayyab/) with karma: 59 on 2013-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0